# Magento | Algolia Search | Add-To-Cart | Reloads | Ajax Failure

Tags: algolia, magento2.4

I have applied the following settings under Magento → Admin → Algolia Search

- Enable Instant Search Results Page => Yes
- Add to Cart => Yes

At the front-end, the search page behavior is surprising.

Click on the “Add-To-Cart” button the page reloads and success message appears.

The Ajax functionality doesn’t work at all the time.

**Steps to reproduce:**

- Magento mini-search, search any term.
- On the search page, click add-to-cart.
- On the search page, input and search any term in the “Algolia mini-search”.
- After results, click add-to-cart.

Please check the attached screenshots.

Thanks,
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after many hours of efforts I’m able to resolve it.
The solution is explained in this forum.

https://discourse.algolia.com/t/magento-2-4-4-p2-search-page-add-to-cart-reloads-ajax-failure/18623

Thanks,